# Regex for integers and decimal

Tags: regex

Looking for a regex for the following

1. Should match value before decimal place.(should return `5` if value is `5.4`)
2. Whole number should be matched as it it (`2` in case of `2` and `4` in case of `4`).

The numbers could be `1.2, 2.4, 2.5566, 3.555, 1, 2, 8`

Regex should match `1`, `2`, `2`, `3,` `1`, `2`, `8`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [RegEx for both, integer and float](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14550526/regex-for-both-integer-and-float)

Comment: Did you try *anything*?

Comment: \d*(\.\d{})? tested same of various tester websites but all giving different results.

Comment: Which language is it? Do you deal with strings or with numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:^|[^.0-9])([0-9]+)
```

This regex will not match digits that happen after a decimal point, or other numbers that happen after a decimal point.

In other words, it's the same number you would get if you extracted a float and then used `Math.floor()` (or equivalent).

You can find the result in the first capture group.

Comment: @DineshhBhardwaj Please don't add solved to your question title. You need to [accept my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it helped you.