# Extract decimal numbers from string in Sparklyr

Tags: r, regex, apache-spark, sparklyr

I've been trying to extract decimal numbers from strings in sparklyr, but it does not work with the regular syntax you would normally use outside of Spark.

I have tried using regexp_extract but it returns empty strings.

```
regexp_extract($170.5M, "[[:digit:]]+\\.*[[:digit:]]*")
```

I'm trying to get 170.5 as a result.

Comment: Try `regexp_extract(col_value, "[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `regexpr` from base R

```
v <- "$170.5M"
regmatches(v, regexpr("\\d*\\.\\d", v))
# [1] "170.5"
```

Answer (score 0):

You may  use

```
regexp_extract(col_value, "[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?")
```

Or

```
regexp_extract(col_value, "\\p{Digit}+(?:\\.\\p{Digit}+)?")
```

Your `[[:digit:]]+\.*[[:digit:]]*` regex does not work, becuae `regexp_extract` expects a Java compatible regex pattern and that engine does not support POSIX character classes in the `[:classname:]` syntax. You may use `digit` POSIX character class like `\p{Digit}`, see [Java regex documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

See [`regexp_extract` documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.2/api/R/regexp_extract.html):

> Extract a specific(idx) group identified by a java regex, from the specified string column.

Comment: regexp_extract(col_value, "[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]+)?") doesn't work when you have a value like .85

Comment: @Neels It depends on the numeric format you need to extract. If `.` can come with no digit in front, use `"[0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+"`. There are a [ton of number matching regexps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14550526/3832970), this answer shows how to use them.