# How to validate integers and max float digits in one rule in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

Hey guys I need to validate something on my laravel application and I don't know how.

So if the user introduces **1234.55** it should allow it, because it have only 5 numbers, but if the user introduces **12345678.55** must reject!

What I have until now.

```
return [
    'max_debit' => 'required|numeric|min:0'
];
```

I tried to use `digits_between`, but when I use this, the validation doesn't allow float numbers.

So the rule should match:

- Integer numbers
- Float numbers -> All greater or equal to 0
- Max digits: `9`
- Accept: `1234.55`
- Reject: `12345678.55`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with the regex rule: https://laravel.com/docs/master/validation#rule-regex

```
'max_debit' => [
    'required',
    'max:9',
    'regex:/^(([0-9]*)(\.([0-9]+))?)$/',
],
```

With the `max` you define a maximum of 9 characters.
If you want to limit the digits after the period, you can add the `{0,2}` group where `0` stands for zero digits and `2` for max 2 digits after the period:

```
/^(([0-9]*)(\.([0-9]{0,2}+))?)$/
```

Answer based on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23059703/6385459

Is this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

You Can use max:9 (max numeric value) or use also custom role in laravel

Comment: Although this answer is correct, it is not exactly what the author asked for. Keep in mind to carefully read the question of the author.